# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' MYsql

Tags: python, mysql

So this is the piece of code that is giving me the error

```
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS", str(share_name), "(nickname VARCHAR(255), date VARCHAR(255), bill VARCHAR(255), quantity VARCHAR(255), rate VARCHAR(255), amount(255))")
insert = f"INSERT INTO", str(share_name), "(nickname) VALUES (%s)"
val = str(share_nick)
mycursor.execute(insert, val)
```

p
and this is the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Shourya Kumar.DESKTOP-M2TQLD2\Desktop\papa project\addshare.py", line 36, in submit
    mycursor.execute(insert, val)
  File "C:\Users\Shourya Kumar.DESKTOP-M2TQLD2\Desktop\papa project\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 545, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

line 36 is this one `mycursor.execute(insert, val)`

I have just given the code that is actually fiving the error, if you guys need the rest of the code, tell me Ill upload a link

Comment: You are using `execute()` wrongly. The first argument is an SQL template, the second is a *sequence* of values for the template.

Comment: Change `val = str(share_nick)` to `val = (str(share_nick),)`.

Comment: @acw1668 still same error

Comment: The error is due to the line `insert = ...` which makes `insert` a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first all of your `insert` variable is tuple you are not usign correctly formatting or `f` string

```
insert = f"INSERT INTO {share_name} (nickname) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.execute(insert, val)
```

i am adding full code so

```
share_name = 'tableName' # your table name
cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {share_name} (nickname VARCHAR(255) , date VARCHAR(255), bill VARCHAR(255), quantity VARCHAR(255), rate VARCHAR(255), amount varchar(255))") #you don't have varchar in amount column

insert = f"INSERT INTO {share_name} (nickname) VALUES (%s)" # 

cursor.execute(insert, (1,))
cnx.commit() #commit is necessary to perform real insert 

cnx.close()
```

Comment: @gaurav now its showing an error code about incorrect sql syntax in `mysql.execute(insert, val)`

Comment: @TubesMyth      you have to add rest of column  and their values in sql .

Comment: `mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS", str(share_name), "(nickname VARCHAR(255)")
insert = f"INSERT INTO", str(share_name), "(nickname) VALUES (%s)"
val = str(share_nick)
mycursor.execute(insert, val)`

I am using this code now but it still gives the same error @gaurav
 sorry about the spaces, if you can help me on any other platform please tell me

Comment: that isn't working me, so basically [this](https://pastebin.com/aPxBk3m6) is the whole code, can you take out some time and edit this @gaurav

Comment: @gaurav but I modified it to just add one column

Comment: @TubesMyth     I mistakely said you have add all six values  which is wrong default values is Null there. secondly for single value you have to add comma in values tuple see the link [NOTE] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)  now updated code will work